# VS2012 skipping lines

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I have such a code:

```
QVector<Point> legalMoves = field.getLegalMoves();
QVector<Cell> costs;
costs.reserve(legalMoves.size());
for (QVector<Point>::iterator i = legalMoves.begin(); i < legalMoves.end(); ++i)
    costs.push_back(checkCost(field, *i, player, -100, 100));
Cell cost;
if (player)  {
    QVector<Point>::iterator m1 = legalMoves.begin();
    QVector<Cell>::iterator m2 = costs.begin();
    QVector<Cell>::iterator j = costs.begin() + 1;
    for (QVector<Point>::iterator i = legalMoves.begin() + 1; i < legalMoves.end(); ++i, ++j)
        if (j->status > m2->status) {
            m1 = i;
            m2 = j;
        }
    cost=*m2;
}
else  {
    QVector<Point>::iterator m1 = legalMoves.begin();
    QVector<Cell>::iterator m2 = costs.begin();
    QVector<Cell>::iterator j = costs.begin() + 1;
    for (QVector<Point>::iterator i = legalMoves.begin() + 1; i < legalMoves.end(); ++i, ++j)
        if (j->status < m2->status) {
            m1 = i;
            m2 = j;
        }
    cost=*m2;
}
QVector<Point> moves;
QVector<Cell>::iterator j = costs.begin();
for (QVector<Point>::iterator i = legalMoves.begin(); i < legalMoves.end(); ++i, ++j)
    if (j->status == cost.status)
        moves.push_back(*i);
short index = qrand()%moves.size();
return moves[index];
```

}

When i'm debugging it, compiler just skips this parts inside loops:

```
if (j->status < m2->status) {
                m1 = i;
                m2 = j;
            }
```

which means the functions returns the very first Point(or any other Point with same Cell value instead of min/max). Why does that happen and how is it possible to fix it?

Comment: have you tried `i != legalMoves.end()` instead of `i < legalMoves.end()` ?

Comment: "I have such a code" - Oy, vat a code he has!  ;-)

Comment: @yiding that didn't help